# How can I make the callable in ListeningExecutorService exexuted infinitely?

Tags: java, guava

The thing is, I want the callable I put in the ListeningExecutorService to keep executing infinitely, and trigger callbacks each time it exexutes.

How can I do that?

Comment: Why not just pass in a `Callable` that doesn't stop running?

Comment: @LouisWasserman Each time the callbacks are triggerred, the returned value of the call() in callable will be used as parameter of the callback's onSuccess

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like perhaps you want a [Service](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ServiceExplained) that runs a loop and has some callback that's notified for each run.

There isn't anything that I know of for executing a `Callable` repeatedly. There's `ScheduledExecutorService` and its listening equivalent `ListeningScheduledExecutorService` which can execute `Runnable`s repeatedly, but not `Callable`s.